# Angular HTML bind with unclosed tags

Tags: angular

I'm try to display html code. I have two pieces of code, one is header, other is footer. I need to insert router-outlet in between. Problem is that header have unclosed tags and they are closed in footer. When I try bind with [innerHTML], angular adds div tag around my code and this mess up display. Is it possible to add html code other way?

```
<div [innerHTML]="header | keepHtml"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div [innerHTML]="footer | keepHtml"></div>
```

There is my code, what I have now. I aslo tried join code in my api, but then router-outled doesn't work.

Let's say i header code is:

```
<div id="firstDiv"><div id="secondDiv"><p>Some text</p>
```

and footer:

```
</div></div>
```

I need router-outlet to be in second div after p tag, but ouput I get is:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="">
<div id="firstDiv">
<div id="secondDiv">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
<div _ngcontent-c0=""></div>
```

P.S I get HTML code from other api, that I can't change.

Comment: check domsenetizer for angular as you are trying to play with html

Comment: can you provide data which you are bind in [innerHTML]?

Comment: is there any chance to make header and footer valid html?

Comment: Added code exmaple to question

Comment: @TomasKuzminskas You cannot use invalid template in Angular. If you don't have a chance to use valid one, consider other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Common header and footer, You can make changes and add APIs in it according to your need.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: I get html code from other API, that i can't change.